# pygame collision with ceiling?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I've only seen information about collisions with walls on here but I'm having a problem making the player "bump" its head on the ceiling. Instead of hitting its head, velocity being set to 0 and it accelerating back down due to gravity, the object gets sucked up ontop of the platform above it. Why isn't this working and how can I fix it? I'm following a tutorial and trailing off to my own adaptation and the content creator said that it would be hard to implement. Apparently there may also be an error if you collide diagonally? (according to the content creator)

Thank you so much in advance, teacher wants me to create something to present infront of people in only a couple of days with no experience with any sort of game engine.

```
def update(self):
    # Game Loop - Update
    self.all_sprites.update()
    # check if player hits a platform
    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.player,self.platforms , False)
    if self.player.vel.y > 0:
        if hits:
            self.player.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top
            self.player.vel.y = 0
    if self.player.vel.y < 0:
        if hits:
            self.player.rect.top = hits[0].rect.bottom
            self.player.vel.y = 0
```

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ might have some help

Comment: So you do `self.player.vel.y = 0` in your if statements, but is that value ever changed elsewhere? If it isn't, neither of your if statements are going to be true, so nothing will change.

Comment: I have a player class which has things such as velocity and acceleration, movement works and I can land ontop of things (first if statement works), I just can't get it to hit the bottom of the rectangle hitbox and stop. The issue is not about the velocity, but more so the placement of the player once the collision happens. Still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead setting the velocity to 0, you might want to set the velocity to -1 or some other negative value to force movement 'downward' out of the boundary condition. You could also add acceleration if desired in the same condition:

```
if hits:
        self.player.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top
        self.player.vel.y = -1  # example velocity
        self.player.acc.y = 2   # example acceleration
```

Comment: Excellent thank you so much, the only issue is that the player then gets stuck on the ceiling for about 2 seconds, I assume that the player is still being pushed upwards until obviously gravity deccelerates the player back down. Any solutions? It seems like the players velocity isn't actually changing? sorry im very new to this

Comment: Im starting to think it's not a problem with the acceleration but the player thinking it's colliding again and getting stuck in a loop. 
EDIT: nevermind, I changed the player pos y to hits[0].rect.bottom - 30 so there are no collision errors, thanks!

Comment: Yea the idea is that you have to get out of your boundary condition somewhere in your code so your suggestion of 'player pos y to hits[0].rect.bottom - 30' does exactly that. Hope my answer helped though!